# Upgrade from Debian 9 to 10 - Mariadb got removed?

Tags: debian, mariadb

I had a Debian 9 environment running, full LAMP stack operational with MariaDB.

I then upgraded from Debian 9 to 10.  Rebooted, everything checked out ok, upgrade was complete.  LAMP environment was good.

Then I decided to `sudo apt autoremove`.  Certainly that is what did me in.  But why the heck would it remove all of MariaDB??

After another reboot, tried to access my site. No database server.  I was able to `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server` and I see I'm back to square one.

Luckily this was entirely a test environment and had everything backed up.  But what am I missing, why would MariaDB be removed.

My ONLY thought is that, in Debian 9 I believe it was called mysql-server and now it's mariadb-server.  So the name change?